# Data not being saved to the table

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgnitor and trying to save data to MYSQL - When I press the submit button the pages refreshes and nothing saved in the table.

At first I thought it was because I missed the `<form>` tags, but adding them made no difference.

CodeIgniter is still new so hopefully its something simple I have missed off.

**Model:**

```
/* Insert postcodes to table*/
function saverecords($postCode,$delivery)
{
    $query="insert into postCodes values('','$postCode','$delivery')";
    $this->db->query($query);
}
```

**Controller**

```
class Backend extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');

        // Set user's selected language.
        if ($this->session->userdata('language'))
        {
            $this->config->set_item('language', $this->session->userdata('language'));
            $this->lang->load('translations', $this->session->userdata('language'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->lang->load('translations', $this->config->item('language')); // default
        }

        /* load database libray manually */
        $this->load->database();

        /* load Model */
        $this->load->model('Settings_model');
    }

    public function savedata()
    {
        /* load registration view form */
        $this->load->view('insert');

        /* Check submit button */
        if($this->input->post('savePostcode'))
        {
            $first_name=$this->input->post('postCode');
            $last_name=$this->input->post('delivery');

            $this->Settings_model->saverecords($postCode,$delivery);
            echo "Records Saved Successfully";
        }
    }
```

**Main Page**

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postcode">Enter Postcode Area</label>
        <input style="font-size:12px" name="postCode" id="postcode" class="form-control required" value="e.g CF11">
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="deliveryCost">Delivery Charge</label>
        <input style="font-size:12px" name="delivery" id="deliveryCost" class="form-control required" value="e.g 5.00">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="save-settings btn btn-primary btn-xs"
        title="<?= lang('save') ?>">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
        <?= lang('save') ?>
    </button>
    <input type="submit" name="savePostcode" value="Save Data"/>
</form>
```

Comment: For starters, your form has a mehod (`post`) but no action defined. So nothing is ever going to happen when you try to submit it

Comment: Thanks, I actually used a how-to manual to get this far and that's how it was setup. Im not sure what I need to do then in this instance to get it working

Comment: You definitely need `<form>` tags, and as others have mentioned, you need to add an `action` to it.  That `action` needs to be [mapped with a route](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) to point to your `savedata()` method.  The CodeIgniter docs include [a basic tutorial with a form that writes to a database](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html), I'd start with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your form has no `action` defined, so nothing will happen when you click the submit button.

The first thing you need to do, which is actually not related to Codeigniter but to how HTML forms are built is to change this:

```
<form method="post">
```

for this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('backend/savedata'); ?>">
```

this will actually post the data to your `savedata` method in the `backend` controller.

Comment: Im trying to understand this a bit. Am I expected to have a file in the directory backend/savedata? In backend there is a file called settings.php that's where the form post is located

Comment: No. `backend` is the name of your controller as defined in `class Backend extends CI_Controller`. `savedata` is a method you declared in your controller (`public function savedata()`). I realize you're struggling not only with HTML but with the whole model-view-controller architecture. You should really dive into the Codeigniter documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="insert into postCodes (colname1,colname2,colname3) values('','$postCode','$delivery')";
```

I think the query has mistaken here

Comment: What is the mistake? :-) An answer should give an answer.

Comment: [Code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Debug and check whether the values of $postCode and $delivery get passed in to the Model.
if it is, simply use this.

```
 $data = array(
    'postCode' => $postCode,
    'delivery' => $delivery

 );

 $this->db->insert('postCodes ', $data);
```